# HttpClient reads incomplete or malformed string

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, json.net, prism, dotnet-httpclient

Im trying to figure out which part of my app (Xamarin Forms and proxy written in PHP) is buggy. Firstly I thought that my proxy (written in PHP) is working incorrectly with long set of data (ie. json containing 1.300.000 characters) and returns malformed response, but every single request with Postman gives me correct JSON, which is successfully decoded with third-party tools. So I assume, proxy is working well.

The problem is (I guess) with decoding response in my Xamarin Forms (2.0.0-beta.22) app. I'm using `HttpClient` to read response with this code:

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var entries = new List<HistoryEntry>();
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
_loggerService.Error(content);
```

`response` is just `GetAsync` response from `HttpClient`. The problem is: `content` is randomly incomplete/malformed. Saying this I mean last character is missing (`}`) or JSON keys/values have additional `"` character, which breaks everything. Unfortunately, I can make exactly the same requests many times and once it works, once not. I found out that this behavior happens only with large set of data (as I mentioned before, long JSON string).

Is there any possibility that `ReadAsStringAsync` does not wait for full response or in any way alters my response string? How can I find the reason of wrongly downloaded data?

**EDIT 21.05.2019:**

Just copied valid JSON (available here: https://github.com/jabools/xamarin/blob/master/json.txt) and returned it from Lumen app by `response()->json(json_decode(..., true))` and still the same result. Hope someone will be able to reproduce this and help me with this issue :( More informations in comments.

Used this code in C#:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("<URL_TO_PHP>");
                    //var response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized: " + i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: is this is  reproducible I would file a bug with Xamarin and include a test case

Comment: I just realized this happens only inside my app. If I copy necessary code for requests to new project, everything is working fine (no errors while decoding JSON). Is it possible that decoding it in new thread is not working as expected?

Comment: Furthermore, problem seems to appear only if I execute code in ViewModel (I use Prism Framework). Moving code to App.xaml.cs results in successfull decode.

Comment: I think you should compare what's the difference in App.xaml.cs and ViewModel  when running the same code. Try xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to execute the code in Main thread in ViewModel.

Comment: Unfortunately, executing task on Main thread did not help :( Still trying to figure out if my proxy is working well but every test that I tried was successful. Trying to use other source of JSON (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos, 5000 records) and it works well.

Comment: **EDIT:** I've just copied valid JSON response and returned it - I can now exclude invalid proxy.